# How to get image details within an anchor element <a><img src></a>

Tags: node.js, jsdom

I am using nodejs and jsdom, attempting to retrieve images used within anchor tags.

I can enumerate the images using `.querySelectorAll("img");` and the anchors using `.querySelectorAll("img");`.

But I can't seem to find the relationship between the two which is the part that I am after, **to know that the image displayed when clicked navigates to x.**

**sample html**

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">
  <img src="https://s.yimg.com/nq/nr/img/yahoo_mail_global_english_white_1x.png" alt="Yahoo Mail Image">
</a>
```

**Node.js**

```
var links = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll("a");
    links.forEach(function(value){
         console.log('Host: ' + value.hostname);
         console.log('Href: ' + value.href);
         console.log('Text: ' + value.text);
         console.log('HTML: ');
         console.dir(value);
    });
```

Expected result:

link to x is displayed with image.alt "yahoo mail image" and image.src "https://...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your HTML context, I can suggest running queries within the link subtrees:

```js
const {JSDOM} = require("jsdom"); // ^22.0.0

const html = `
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">
  <img src="https://s.yimg.com/nq/nr/img/yahoo_mail_global_english_white_1x.png" alt="Yahoo Mail Image">
</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">
  <img src="google.png" alt="Google Image">
</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com">
  <img src="whatever.png" alt="Whatever Image">
</a>`;

const {window: {document}} = new JSDOM(html);
const data = [...document.querySelectorAll("a")].map(e => ({
  src: e.querySelector("img").src,
  alt: e.querySelector("img").getAttribute("alt"),
  href: e.href,
}));
console.log(data);
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    src: 'https://s.yimg.com/nq/nr/img/yahoo_mail_global_english_white_1x.png',
    alt: 'Yahoo Mail Image',
    href: 'http://www.yahoo.com/'
  },
  {
    src: 'google.png',
    alt: 'Google Image',
    href: 'http://www.google.com/'
  },
  {
    src: 'whatever.png',
    alt: 'Whatever Image',
    href: 'http://www.example.com/'
  }
]
```

However, it's likely that there are other links on the page you're working with, so I would add a parent container to refine your `a` selector, which is probably too broad and will attempt to grab links that don't have `<img>` tags as children.

Using the sizzle pseudoselector `a:has(img)`, xpath, or a fiter (shown below) might also help:

```js
const data = [...document.querySelectorAll("a")]
  .filter(e => e.querySelector(":scope > img"))
  .map(e => ({
    src: e.querySelector("img").src,
    alt: e.querySelector("img").getAttribute("alt"),
    href: e.href,
  }));
```

...but this is speculation.

Comment: Nice answer, I think this has gotten me some progress...